# What does -> mean in gradle scripts

Tags: gradle, groovy

What does the -> operator mean in gradle scripts. Is it a groovy thing? E.g.

```
def configureWarnings = { compiler ->
      compiler.args '-Wno-long-long', '-Wall', '-Wswitch-enum', '-pedantic', '-Werror'
}
```

OR

```
all { binary ->
    binary.component.sources.cpp.libs.each { lib ->
      if (lib instanceof Map && lib.containsKey('library') {
        //blah
      }
      if (lib instanceof Map && lib.containsKey('library')) {
        //blah
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is groovy syntax for parameters in a closure. [See here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_defining_a_closure) for more information

Answer (score 0):

In groovy, this syntax:

> serves to separate the **arguments** from the **closure body**.

[Closures Refference](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html)

They are comma-delimited, in case you have more than one parameter.

A simple example would be:

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

list.each { listItem ->
    println listItem
}
```

Which will result in:

```
a
b
c
```

In this context, you may even omit the parameter, and use the native call *it*. The code would be something like:

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

list.each {
    println it
}
```

Result would, and should, be the same.

If you have a map, for example, you could separate it's keys and values like this:

```
def map = ['Key_A':'a', 'Key_B':'b', 'Key_C':'c']
map.each { key, value ->
    println "$key has the value $value"
}
```

Naturally, the result would be:

```
Key_A has the value a
Key_B has the value b
Key_C has the value c
```

Hope that I've helped.